# 413 Request entity too large when posting any change in the pages

Tags: wordpress, apache, post, request

I have changed the max upload size and the max post size in the `php.ini` file, but that did not help.

I am adding word by word detail of the error that is being displayed:

> Request Entity Too Large
>
> The requested resource /wp-admin/post.php
>   does not allow request data with POST requestsor or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.
>
> Apache Server at Port 80

Comment: I could not post the image as I dont have 10 reputations....

Comment: What size is the image you're trying to upload, just out of interest?

Comment: The size is 420KB of the image that i wanted to upload to help the people solve my question much more easily.

Comment: @Rajeshwar - any luck on this?  I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @Rajeshwar, for reference: you can upload images to `imgur.com` and add the link into questions. If you don't have the reputation to add an inline image, just add a comment like this asking someone to convert it (not in the question though, as that creates extra editing work).